# PostgreSQL: mark current session as "unimportant"

Tags: postgresql

If I want to drop a PostgreSQL DB I get this error:

```
postgres@server:~$ dropdb c123_d
dropdb: database removal failed: ERROR:  
        database "c123_d" is being accessed by other users
DETAIL:  There is 1 other session using the database.
```

I know how to help myself. I can do `select * from pg_stat_activity;` and see what is still running.

In my case it was a `LISTEN`.

Is there a way to mark the LISTEN-statement or this session as "unimportant"? In this context this means that the DB is allowed to kill this statement if the database should get shut-down or dropped.

Is there a way to tell PostgreSQL this?

Comment: The "DB" will never kill session on its own (unless a deadlock is detected)

Comment: Hope this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073773/drop-postgresql-database-through-command-line

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to mark the LISTEN-statement or this session as "unimportant"?

Unimportant to you?  Perhaps.

Unimportant to *Postgres*?  No.

Every connection is as "important" as every other.

If you want to kill off an active connection, look to the **pg_cancel_backend** function.

Comment: Great if postgres thinks every session is important by default. Sad, that there is no way to tell postgres that this is a server waiting for ever in a LISTEN (and kill it, if you are told to drop the db).